# Apply Pagination on two different tables and merge results in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I'm using Spring Data JPA to expose REST APIs. In my application, there are two types of tables available(current and archival) and structure of the current and archival tables are exactly similar and data will be moved for current table to archival table over the period of time for performance reasons. I'm having repository classes to retrieve the data from current and archival table separately and Pagination is also implemented for repositories.

Now I got a requirement to fetch the eligible records from both tables based on criteria and apply pagination at single shot. Is it possible with Spring Data JPA

Comment: If you add some code that would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the latest version in both tables and when you search for data you just do a regular search.

Another option would be to create a view over the two tables.

I also think Hibernate Envers was able to do that though I never tried it.

Comment: I have implemented logic in controller to get List of Entities from both repositories and merge them using utilities. However, I'm trying to find out a way to apply pagination on both repositories and provide consolidated paginated view to client. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In my response I was talking about pagination